# Ionic : Hide splash screen only after the final view has been pushed to the stack

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have following use case in my ionic app which is using [splashsscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) plugin :

**1. If user is not logged in:**

```
Show SplashScreen>  LoginPage is pushed to stack > 
Hide SplashScreen in login page
```

**2. If user is NOT logged in:**

```
Show SplashScreen > Login page pushed to stack> 
Landing page pushed to stack (after user logs in) > Hide SplashScreen.
```

*Expected Behavior:*

In scenario-2, I expect SplashScreen to dismiss and show the Landing Page without showing the Login page

*Actual Behaviour:*

In scenario-2, SplashScreen is dismissed, login page is shown for a split second and then Landing page is shown.

How can I achieve the expected behavior? Please let me know if any code snippet is required.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to [set the splash screen not to be auto hide](https://medium.com/@chrisbenseler/ionic-3-hide-splash-screen-only-when-app-is-ready-f4e624902009):

In config.xml:

```
<preference name=”FadeSplashScreen” value=”false”/>
<preference name=”AutoHideSplashScreen” value=”false”/>
```

In `app.component.ts`, you need to set the `rootPage` to what you want based on the login condition:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    if(userIsLoggedIn){
       this.rootPage = Page1;
       } else {
       this.rootPage = Page2;
    }
     //Now, hide the splash screen.
     this.splashscreen.hide();
   });
```