# How do I make a screen appears only upon installation of the app. The second time that the user opens the app, that screen wont appear again

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How do I make a screen appears only after installation of the app(ionic framework). The second time that the user opens the app, that screen wont appear again.

I want a screen that will only be shown fresh from installation. When the user opens the app for the second time, that screen wont appear again and the app will proceed to your homescreen. Is that possible? Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a storage value, eg. `welcomeScreenDisplayed = false` and check it's value when the app starts. After it starts, you change the value of the storage variable.

If you need to preload data before the actual app starts, you may try to use APP_INITIALIZER:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-load-data-before-your-angular-app-starts-71083cf56132?source=rss------javascript-5
https://medium.com/@mohd2sh/load-data-before-the-app-starts-in-angular-2-3b1927aa502c

#### Edit

What do you mean exactly by screen? If you refer to a splash screen (the screen that shows up when app is starting), then you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953125/ionic-hide-splash-screen-only-after-the-final-view-has-been-pushed-to-the-stac).

If you mean additional in-app screen, you need to store the information somewhere in the app if the screen was displayed or not. Ionic does not have this mechanism by default, you need to add a plugin that will allow you to store data in the phone's memory. To do that you can use [ionic-storage plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage).

So what you want to do:

1. create a StorageService that will get and set data in the storage memory
2. in the `AppComponent` check if there is `welcomeScreenDisplayed` variable set in the store, and read it's value.
3. if it's false, then you can display the welcome screen and then set the `welcomeScreenDisplayed` to `true`, so next time the screen won't be displayed
4. if it's true, it means that you don't need to display it again and you do nothing

Comment: how do I know that the app was opened the second time? is there a way to do that? sorry im new to this ionic/angular.. and im not even a mid-level programmer in general haha im still on my learning journey

Comment: @lerd the key is what do you mean by welcome screen? If you refer to a splash screen, then you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953125/ionic-hide-splash-screen-only-after-the-final-view-has-been-pushed-to-the-stac). If you have additional welcome screen, then it's a bit easier.

Comment: @akkonrad Since ionic replaced the storage module with capacitor Preferences does your anwsear still apply? is there another way this could be done?